# Dynamic article filter

Tags: plugin, articles

I'm trying to build a dynamic "gallery" for categories/articles on my site.

Essentially, there will be 3 dropdown menus at the top:

**Refine By:  COUNTRY | HOLIDAY | LOCATION**

and each one will have a number of options.  Depending on the options the results will be shown as article thumbs underneath, 4 across.

[image]

I've looked around for a good module plugin to use but unbelievably I can only find one that fits my exact requirements.  I clearly can't be loooking hard enough, so can anyone advise on a good plugin?

Answer (score 4):

[RokSprocket plugin](http://www.rockettheme.com/docs/joomla/extensions/roksprocket/) in its [Mosaic layout mode](http://www.rockettheme.com/docs/joomla/extensions/roksprocket/mosaic_mode.md) does exactly what you shown on screen clipping. I'm using that plugin and it works well.

You can also check the [demo of Mosaic layout mode](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla-extensions/roksprocket/). Choose the **Mosaic** menu item.

Comment: Does that allow you to add 3 different filters though?

Essentially what we need is 1 filter for categories, and then 2 further filters for Tags

Comment: AFAIK not out-of-the box. The filters there are only for tags. Tag clicked shows only items where it is in effect. Category filtering is possible by multiple plugin instances, one category each. At the moment I'm in doubt whether anyone has made multi-field filtering (category, tag, date, ...) available, because this makes the thing unnecessarily complicated. For me your requirement looks like one for advanced commercial extension. Maybe it will appear in one of answers here, but from my side I'm not aware of such.

Answer (score 3):

I used [Minitek Wall](https://www.minitek.gr/joomla-extensions/minitek-wall). 
Seems to work really well - I am not technically well versed so I stand to be corrected on that part. Very quick. 
Only frustrating thing is the lack of pagination in the free version - but that seems like a good driver to the paid version!